# Handling Unmanaged Code within .Net

Tags: c#, printing, unmanaged

I have a c# component which needs to use unmanaged code, in particular the [winspool.drv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is a client for the Printer Spooling service. Every so often a call will freeze causing the component to hang.

What are my options in terms of handling unmanaged code which is hanging/freezing?

My ideal scenario would be

1. Make a call to the winspool.drv
2. If call is hanging, restart the Printer Pool service and try again.

Comment: Restarting the print spooler because your client is buggy is quite sub-optimal. You need to fix your code, not workaround the issues caused by it.

Comment: Run it as Task() and cancel when timeout expire.

Comment: Yes, completely agree with @CodeCaster. You need to fix bugs.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I agree but sometimes the world is suboptimal. I never said my code caused the issue with the printer service...

Comment: Main question is why are your calls to winspool.drv hanging? Is it due to the printer driver or your code? Review your p/invoke declarations and interop code, make sure it complies with MSDN references - if you are experimenting undocumented p/invoke calls be prepared to allocate **a lot** of time for the task at hand.

Comment: @bokibeg Thanks for your comment. It's unclear at this stage what is causing the printer service to hang. I do know that it hangs randomly regardless of the application or not which leads me to believe its not the apps issue. The call that's being made is to get printers across a network.